# Compiling project with LLVM MAC OS X causes linker error

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, llvm

I installed LLVM with brew

```
brew install llvm
```

in a test c++ file:

```
#include <llvm/IR/Value.h>
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>

int main()
{
    llvm::LLVMContext context;
    llvm::Module *module = new llvm::Module("module", context);

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
BIN=main
SRC_FILES=main.cpp
FLAGS := $(shell llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs)

CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
CXX=$(CC)++

all:
        $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(SRC_FILES)
```

When I run `make`

It gives me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_del_curterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.cpp.o)
  "_set_curterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.cpp.o)
  "_setupterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.cpp.o)
  "_tigetnum", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up needing `--system-libs` as a flag in the `llvm-config` command:

```
FLAGS := $(shell llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs --system-libs)
```